# Migrate Sql Server 2000. Which is better, 2005 vs 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration

My company has a Server with Windows Server 2003, and SQL Server 2000. We are planning to migrate just the database server, a provider said us the migration would be better to 2005 first, and then to 2008, because "the SQL Server 2008 is best suited for Windows Server 2008".

Which are the pros and cons of each of these approaches?

- Migrate SQL 2000 to SQL 2005 and then to SQL 2008
- Migrate SQL 2000 directly to SQL 2008

**NOTE**: Changing Operating System is not an option ($$$) right now for the company.

Any article or experiences would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 is leaving mainstream support early next year ([>clicky<](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2855)) so if you were to use that you may be looking at another upgrade sooner than you would like.  Additionally, Microsoft's [Hardware and Software Requirements page for SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) indicates that it works Just Fine on Server 2003 (SP2).

I'd go 2008, and would have a healthy dose of suspicion that your provider's motives might not be 100% honest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to upvote mh, but I want to...  He is exactly right in my opinion.

Another factor to throw in there are the code changes that are necessary to get your applications up to the new edition.  While fewer than 200 -> 2005, there are changes to the optimizer and engine from 2005 to 2008, and there is code that will execute on one and not the other.  The point really is do you want to go through the expense of fixing all of the bugs twice or once.  I would say leap frog to 08 (maybe even R2) and be stable for some time. [Sql 2008 R2 release dates](http://blogs.technet.com/dataplatforminsider/archive/2010/01/19/sql-server-2008-r2-gets-an-official-date.aspx)

Comment: go, vote him up :D

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2008. For one reason alone: [**Page Compression**](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-2008-page-compression-performance-impact-on-table-scans.aspx). On *many* loads the benefits can be spectacular, and it comes basically for free (no application change required). Truth in advertising though: not *all* workloads will benefit form it, and it requires enterprise edition. but if you do have EE deployed and plan to upgrade, testing your load on an eval version of SQL 2008 after you compressed the big tables may reveal some very nice results.